# Failed to set event handler in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an event handler for input text controls. The controls is generated dynamically. My code is like:

**JavaScript**:

```
var settings_check = new Array("checkVMName()","checkDiskMB()","checkMemMB()","checkEsx()","checkDatastore()");
...
_inputbox = document.createElement("input");
_inputbox.type = "text";
_inputbox.id = settings[zindex];
_inputbox.onblur = settings_check[zindex];

_hint = document.createElement("hint");
_hint.id = settings[zindex] + "_Label2";
_hint.innerText = settings_hint[zindex];

mycurrent_cel2.appendChild(_inputbox);
mycurrent_cel2.appendChild(_hint);
```

But this way doesn't work. I checked the HTML with Firebug, and no "onblur" attribute for the input text control at all.

**HTML**

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>....</td>
>   <td><input type="text" id="Datastore">
>       <hint id="Datastore_Label2">start with /</hint>
>   </td>
> </tr>
> ```

I also tried other ways to set event handler like

```
_inputbox.onblur = function(){alert("test");};
```

or

```
_inputbox.setAttribute("onblur",func);
```

Neither works. :(

If I manually add onblur=function(){...} for the input text control in the HTML with Firebug and execute, the onblur does work. So the question is: how can I set event handler for a control in JavaScript? Is there anything wrong in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an array of strings with function invocations in them, this is completely incorrect.

You need to assign *references* to the functions that you wish to be invoked when the event fires. You'd do this by simply storing the names of the functions (without the `()` or quotes) in your array, and it should work (the functions must be previously defined in the current scope as well):

```
var settings_check = [checkVMName, checkDiskMB, checkMemMB, checkEsx, checkDatastore];
```

So, in essence, `settings_check` is simply an array of function references.

See this [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6mcz/) illustrating this concept.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. I believe you are right even I've not tried your suggestion because the code is in my home PC and I'm not at home now. I'll let you know after I try. Thanks again!

Comment: sorry for a late update. After I modified my code - assign references to the functions as you suggested, the code still failed to call the event handler. In the DOM view of Firebug, I can see the onblur attribute has been assigned to the function. But it just can't be called. So I think maybe there are more than one error in my code. With your help, I fixed the first one, but still tried to figure the left... Do you have any suggestion? I'm considering asking a new question about it. Thanks

Comment: @Landy Feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422093/failed-to-set-event-handler-in-javascript. Thanks for your suggestion.