# Failed to set event handler

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

This question is a follow up of post [Failed to set event handler in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383137/failed-to-set-event-handler-in-javascript)

I want to add an event handler for input text controls. The input box control is generated dynamically. My code is like:

```
_inputbox = document.createElement("input");
_inputbox.type = "text";
_inputbox.id = settings[zindex];
_inputbox.onblur = checkName;
```

`checkName()` is defined previously. But when I input something in the box and move the focus to other control, the `checkName()` isn't executed.

In the DOM tab of Firebug, I find the `onblur` is assigned to `checkName()` correctly.

In the HTML tab of Firebug, I find the input box only defines an "ID" and a "type". No `onblur` in its HTML code. If I edit the HTML and add `onblur=checkName()` manually. The function can be called successfully.

HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="Datastore">
```

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PvLew/. Is `checkName` in the scope where you assign it?

Comment: @Felix Thank you. Actually the input box will be append to a cell as a part of table. I'm trying to isolate the code to find where the root reason is.

Comment: Are you sure your page is not cached and you are looking at old code that did not add an event handler?

Comment: Can you post the actual code, as Felix says, as posted it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
If(_inputbox.addEventListener) {
    _inputbox.addEventListener('blur', checkName, false);
} else { 
    _inputbox.attachEvent('onblur', checkName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. The code is executed without any error, but in the DOM tab of Firebug, the 'blur' attribute is still 'blur()'.